# Using labels/attributes from arcMap to display information

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-silverlight-api, wpf

I am wanting to take the labels/attributes that are used in arcMap and display them in an InfoWindow when the user clicks on the map point. I really have no idea where to start on this so any help would be appreciated. I have attached a screen shot of my arcMap with the labels as well as a screen shot of where I am wanting the labels to appear. If you look at the picture titled 'InfoWindow,' Utah is displayed when the user clicks on the state.

Here is the xaml I have used with my maps so far:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Background="#FFE3E3E3" WrapAround="True" MouseClick="MyMap_MouseClick" MouseRightButtonDown="MyMap_MouseRightButtonDown" Extent="-9834972.92753924,4441899.425293319,-9833977.88119163, 4442762.485358352">
                <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer" Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" />
<esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer  ID="ID" Url="This is where the URL is."/>
</esri:Map>

            <Border Background="{StaticResource PanelGradient}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="20" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Black" >
                <esri:Legend Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"
                         LayerIDs="ID"
                         LayerItemsMode="Tree"
                         ShowOnlyVisibleLayers="False"
                         Refreshed="Legend_Refreshed">
                    <esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" >
                                </CheckBox>
                                <Slider Maximum="1" Value="{Binding Layer.Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="50" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
                    <esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" >
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
                </esri:Legend>
            </Border>
```

If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask! Thanks again!
[image: Labels]
[image: InfoWindow]

Comment: If this is using the ArcGIS API for Silverlight then you may want to put a title and tag(s) on it that attracts AGS/Silverlight developers to it - at the moment I suspect they will see the title and think its ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: I do not see any screenshots.

Comment: Sorry about that. I completely forgot to add them. You should now see the pictures. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I am still confused, perhaps even moreso now :) What do ArcMap and the ArcGIS Silverlight API have to do with each other? Are you developing an ArcMap customization or a Silverlight application?

Comment: Haha sorry about that. I am developing a WPF application. I am using arcMap to create the map package that I am using in the application. arcMap has all of the data in it and I can make the labels show up. I would like to be able to make the labels show up in the info windows. Or at least be able to pull the information out of the arcMap and display it in the info window.

Comment: Okay, I would include that info in your question. Hopefully that is enough for someone familiar with that API to help you out, as I don't think I can. It sounds like the labels themselves are unimportant, rather there are particular feature **attributes** you want to display in a pop-up window.